# Python cartesian product in nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, cartesian-product

I know that in order to get the combination of an list of list the cartesian product must be used, but in my case I need the result to be a dictionary where combination subgroups are nested inside so I can use the result as a JSON for a recursive angular directive that shows elements nested in N depth levels.

Here is a data input example:

```
[
    [{"cluster_id":1,"id":1,"name":"A"}, {"cluster_id":1,"id":2,"name":"B"}, {"cluster_id":1,"id":3,"name":"C"}],
    [{"cluster_id":2,"id":1,"name":"D"}, {"cluster_id":2,"id":2,"name":"E"}, {"cluster_id":2,"id":3,"name":"F"}],
    [{"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"}, {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"}, {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"}]
]
```

That should result like this:

```
[{"cluster_id":1,"id":1,"name":"A", "subcluster": [
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":1,"name":"D", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        },
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":2,"name":"E", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        },
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":3,"name":"F", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{"cluster_id":1,"id":2,"name":"B", "subcluster": [
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":1,"name":"D", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        },
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":2,"name":"E", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        },
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":3,"name":"F", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{"cluster_id":1,"id":3,"name":"C", "subcluster": [
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":1,"name":"D", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        },
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":2,"name":"E", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        },
        {"cluster_id":2,"id":3,"name":"F", "subcluster": [
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":1,"name":"G"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":2,"name":"H"},
                {"cluster_id":3,"id":3,"name":"I"},
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I would like to know how to generate this output using Pyhton if possible, but any help is welcome.

Comment: Any attempts on your part?

Comment: I have calculated the cartesian product with itertools product but I am unable to format the result as the output I mention, I have also tried to generate te output using a recursive function using mentioned input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it with the following recursive function:

```
def generate_tree(filters, depth):
    if depth == len(filters)-1:
        return filters[depth]
    else:
        return [{'name': i['name'], 'id': i['id'], 'cycle_cluster_id': i['cycle_cluster_id'], 'subcluster': generate_tree(filters, depth+1)} for i in filters[depth]]
```